# Cutsom Input for formtastic, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have made a custom input method for formtastic, it is designed to work with carrierwave and it works great but with one exception, the preview image and other html will not render, as it is being sanitized (i think).

Am i going about this completely the wrong way?

Here is the code:

```
def carrierwave_input(method, options)
   c = basic_input_helper(:file_field, :string, method, options) 

   c += hidden_input((method.to_s+"_cache").to_sym, {})


   if object.send("#{method.to_s}?")
     c += %{<img src="#{object.send("#{method.to_s}_url")}">}
     c += "<br>"
     c += boolean_input(("remove_"+method.to_s).to_sym, {})
   end

return c
```

end

calling with:

```
form.input :thumb, :as => :carrierwave
```

when rendered the image and 
 tags escaped.

how can i get round this.

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this on rails 3? If so, try calling "return c.html_safe"

Comment: unfortunatly not rails 3, but 2.3.8